# Does this sentence need past perfect?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

> The girls were pretty wild. They stayed at my house and they **had bought** cocaine the night before. I woke up the morning and they were still awake

I don't see the necessity of past perfect here as the night before is stated which means the night before they stayed it is crystal clear.

May be if it was **bought** we could think that both events took place the night before, that is the only explication I can find

Answer (score 2):

It is natural to use past perfect in this context.

Here we have a narrative, and the narrator is describing a particular night a which someone was at his house, and later in the narration; he then describes the morning after. Time moves forward in the narration. But in the middle of this he wants to mention events that occured *before* the particular night. This is out of order.

It would be possible to have used the simple past, and it wouldn't have been confusing. However, describing events that happened before a particular time in the past is the function of the past perfect, so it is natural to use it.

Comment: The simplest answer is: they bought the cocaine prior to staying the night.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the Past Perfect or the Past Simple since you've included "**before**".

But don't forget that "**simple is better**"

Comment: I know that but why did the author  choose past perfect in this case? Is it because of a risk of confusing times  or may be buying cocaine has been a recurrent action xxxx has done  for a long time . There must be a reason.

Comment: @user5577 It wouldn't be confusing with Past Simple, so it was simply his choice.